# MDADM rebuild raid 6 with 3 'failed' drives

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

I've ran into the following problem:

My Raid 6 (/dev/md6) failed after 3 disks fell out of the array.
One of the disks must have been out for a while (in SMART, 5 of the 6 disks have an uptime of 1year, the other one has 8months and 21days)

I first tried to add the 3 missing drives back to the array, but sdf1 was 'busy'. the other two i could add.

and it said sdf1 was busy (or something) so i rebooted.
and tried again.

the output is now:

```
root@server:~# mdadm --assemble --run --force --update=resync /dev/md6 /dev/sd[abcdef]1
mdadm: ignoring /dev/sdd1 as it reports /dev/sda1 as failed
mdadm: ignoring /dev/sde1 as it reports /dev/sda1 as failed
mdadm: ignoring /dev/sdc1 as it reports /dev/sda1 as failed
mdadm: Marking array /dev/md6 as 'clean'
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md6: Input/output error
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
```

other clues:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sd[a-f]1 | egrep 'Event|/dev/sd'
/dev/sda1:
         Events : 523989
/dev/sdb1:
         Events : 523989
/dev/sdc1:
         Events : 523989
/dev/sdd1:
         Events : 523989
/dev/sde1:
         Events : 523989
/dev/sdf1:
         Events : 0
```

and

```
root@server:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[abcdef]1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : f0f7a964:3a8f5f80:a539aff3:cab7a6a5
           Name : fileserver:6  (local to host fileserver)
  Creation Time : Mon Mar 16 15:07:55 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813774957 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 15627548672 (14903.59 GiB 16002.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813774336 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 839401fb:04c596d0:78eca459:78d3d7fc

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Dec 15 12:46:10 2015
       Checksum : f1607072 - correct
         Events : 523989

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : AAA.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : f0f7a964:3a8f5f80:a539aff3:cab7a6a5
           Name : fileserver:6  (local to host fileserver)
  Creation Time : Mon Mar 16 15:07:55 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813774957 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 15627548672 (14903.59 GiB 16002.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813774336 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a887f904:144d0e39:b306b3a6:29f0a22b

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jan  4 19:43:04 2016
       Checksum : dfc3e244 - correct
         Events : 523989

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : f0f7a964:3a8f5f80:a539aff3:cab7a6a5
           Name : fileserver:6  (local to host fileserver)
  Creation Time : Mon Mar 16 15:07:55 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813775360 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 15627548672 (14903.59 GiB 16002.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813774336 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 258048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 87c811fc:b96d2e28:459ae3a6:917b380e

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jan  4 20:03:32 2016
       Checksum : a8c5591f - correct
         Events : 523989

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : .AA..A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : f0f7a964:3a8f5f80:a539aff3:cab7a6a5
           Name : fileserver:6  (local to host fileserver)
  Creation Time : Mon Mar 16 15:07:55 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813774957 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 15627548672 (14903.59 GiB 16002.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813774336 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 18880035:fc631ea4:ee518ad5:b94d2720

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jan  4 20:03:32 2016
       Checksum : 9e3a0a2d - correct
         Events : 523989

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .AA..A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : f0f7a964:3a8f5f80:a539aff3:cab7a6a5
           Name : fileserver:6  (local to host fileserver)
  Creation Time : Mon Mar 16 15:07:55 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813774957 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 15627548672 (14903.59 GiB 16002.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813774336 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 6da68475:bc853f0f:b05e6cd1:43f28656

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jan  4 20:03:32 2016
       Checksum : 7c20988f - correct
         Events : 523989

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : .AA..A ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : f0f7a964:3a8f5f80:a539aff3:cab7a6a5
           Name : fileserver:6  (local to host fileserver)
  Creation Time : Mon Mar 16 15:07:55 2015
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7813774957 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
     Array Size : 15627548672 (14903.59 GiB 16002.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 7813774336 (3725.90 GiB 4000.65 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : bef4edfe:272fcf21:2f23e64d:b811cb04

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jan  4 19:43:04 2016
       Checksum : 42cc70aa - correct
         Events : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : AAA.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Total of 6 4TB drives.
any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: RAID 6 can tolerate two failed disks. Now that three disks have failed, you have little to no chance to get your data back.

Comment: @DanielB they haven't actually all failed. They all just disconnected.

Comment: Do you already have up to date backups? If not, first create disk images. If you have (and have checked that they work), then please post what happens if you add the 5 working drives to the system (leave out the 6th which failed earlier) and try the `-force` parameter. (mdadm --assemble --force .....)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the data on the disks is intact (ie. the drives were kicked out of the array for transient faults), you can rebuild the array.  Since five out of the six drives have identical event counts, you probably won't lose any data.

There are two ways you can do this:

1. The fast, high-risk way: `mdadm --assemble --force --run /dev/sd[abcde]1`.  If it works, this will give you an array running in degraded mode (one disk missing), waiting for you to re-add `/dev/sdf` and let it rebuild.
2. The slow, safe way: follow the repair procedure on [the Linux RAID wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID).  The full step-by-step procedure is too long to reproduce here, but the key is that you use `dmsetup` to create an overlay for each component volume of your RAID array, letting you do dry-run repair attempts to see what works, without actually writing to the disks.  Again, you'll be working with drives `/dev/sda1` through `/dev/sde1` to re-assemble the array in degraded mode.

Comment: I had found that page and been using the overlay files. I managed to get the raid to assemble with 4 of the 6 disks, but the rebuild could not work, because one of the disks was missing some events (IE data corruption). but i managed to get nearly all my data off the array.